# Are there any differences between "give someone a helping hand" and "give someone a hand"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

These are from the dictionary

> [a helping hand](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-helping-hand)
>
> help and support
>
> **give/lend/offer etc somebody a helping hand**
>
> *She’s been giving me a helping hand with the children.*

---

> [give (somebody) a hand](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/give-somebody-a-hand)
>
> spoken to help someone do something
>
> *Can you give me a hand?*
>
> **give (somebody) a hand with**
>
> *Shall I give you a hand with that bag?*

---

I guess "**give someone a hand**" is more about helping with physical things such as moving a table or holding a bag for someone. And, "**give someone a helping hand**" is more about helping with non-physical things such as talking children to school or taking care of elderly people or supporting life of someone.

Are there any differences between "**give someone a helping hand**" and "**give someone a hand**"?

Answer (score 2):

"Give [x] a hand" *is* an idiomatic way of saying help someone... however it is also an idiomatic way of *inviting applause* for someone. Context, of course, ought to make it clear which you mean.

"A helping hand" is just a more specific idiom. "Lend a hand" is another.